# Does Core Data take appropriate action automatically when there's a Low Memory Warning?

Tags: iphone, core-data

Does it turn some managed objects into faults when there's a Low Memory Warning? Or must we do that manually by calling the -refreshObjects:mergeChanges: method which puts the affected managed objects on diet quickly? And...would that actually hurt? What if these objects are currently used by an NSFetchedResultsController to show up on a table view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Core Data listens for low memory warnings and will drop its cache and attempt to fault any object that it can to reduce its memory consumption.

If the object is currently being used it would automatically realize that object the next time you accessed on of its properties so from your application's point of view, nothing has happened and no `NSManagedObject` entities have been released.

Comment: Say I have a feed that has many items. Will it fault all of the items if I am using the feed when a memory warning occurs?

Comment: Yes it will fault everything that it can and as soon as you use one of them it will bring it back in transparently.

Answer (score 1):

In the case where you have established a relationship between two objects, you MUST use the managedObjectContext method -refreshObject:mergeChanges:NO after doing a save, to tell CoreData that the related object can be released. I think of it as the moral equivalent to a [object release]; statement; you are telling CoreData to release the object it read it from the DB. The tradeoff, as Marcus says, is that it will be released from memory cache, but have to be read back in by core data. the good news is that it happens behind the scenes and you don't have to program for it; the bad news is that it happens behind the scenes and thus can 'magically' chew up memory.

Ways around it are many; for example, use a predicate to only select the rows you absolutely must need; don't do a general call to fetch everything and then go through the list one by one. More than likely you will crash when you do the general call and CoreData attempts to load all objects.